# How to control or reduced loading time of JS files in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, performance, node-modules

Whenever I load my website that time it takes too much time to load. I checked in browser network and found that few files take time to load and I tried to find those JS files but unable to find it in my system.

```
inline.dd9054597bd29bcc7a43.bundle.js, 
polyfills.493bdd7538c4e955835c.bundle.js, 
vendor.d5562ce25944f1e31ca0.bundle.js, 
main.7d7cae6962bfd55db5f6.bundle.js, 
mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2, 
https://acsbapp.com/apps/app/dist/js/app.js
```

How to improve their loading time ?

[image]

Comment: Pretty slow for those reasonably small files.. how are you hosting this? On one of my sites, those similar js files all load under 100ms..

Comment: running this site on tomcat 8.5 in client machine

Answer (score 0):

You can split your app in modules, and load this modules with **lazy loading** pattern.
Then, they are not be loaded in the beginning (just if you need them afterwards), so the loading time of the bundle is going to be lower.

You have more info about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-feature-modules)

You also can use webs as **[Bundlephobia](https://bundlephobia.com/)** or VSC pluggings as **[import-cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost)** that help you to see the size of your js libraries.